# Convert float value to NSString

Tags: objective-c

Do you know how can i convert float value to nsstring value because with my code, there is an error.

My Code :

```
- (float)percent:(float)a :(float)b{
    return a / b * 100;
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {
  // ....   

    float tx_nb_demande_portabilite = [self percent: [(NSNumber*) [stat nb_demande_portabilite] floatValue] :[(NSNumber*) [stat nb_users] floatValue]];
    NSString *tx_nb_demande_portabilite_st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tx_nb_demande_portabilite];
//....
}
```

The error :

```
EXC_BAD ACCESS for NSString *tx_nb_demande_portabilite_st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tx_nb_demande_portabilite];
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to use `%f` format specifier for float, not `%@`.

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", myFloat];
```

To use specific number of digits after decimal use `%.nf` where n is number of digits after decimal point.

```
// 3 digits after decimal point
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", myFloat];
```

Obj-C uses C `printf` style formatting. Please check [printf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for all other possible formatting.

Answer (score 4):

one more option:

```
NSString * str = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:value].stringValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

`@"%f"` sounds like more appropriate format string for `float`.

Comment: +1 Not only does it "sound like" a more appropriate format - it *is by far* the most appropriate format for a `float` :)

Comment: That's what I meant, just putting it mildly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tx_nb_demande_portabilite];
```

Answer (score 0):

A modern (and less verbose) approach would be:

```
NSString *str = @(myFloat).description;
```