# Draw an int or float value as a NSString in a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert float value to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974702/convert-float-value-to-nsstring)

How can I draw an `int` or `float` in a `UILabel` through an `NSString`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What issue did you hit?  I recommend you go through some intro tutorials and books - folks here are very helpful with specific issues and questions.

Answer (score 4):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", yourIntValue];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", yourFloatValue];
```

Your question has probably been asked before, might be marked as a duplicate. Also, it might be a good idea to follow bryanmac's advice to become "less new to iPhone development"!

Answer (score 4):

In order to change the text on the label, you need to assign its `text` property:

```
mylabel.text = [NSString stringWthFormat:"%d", intVal];
```

The `stringWithFormat:` is very flexible, it lets you create new `NSString`s using a format string as a template, and replacing *format specifiers* with additional data that you can pass to the method. Entries with `%` inside the string get replaced with the data items that you pass. `%d` or `%i` mean "integer", `%f` or `%g` mean "floating point", and so on. [Here is the list of all specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).